# problema compilar source

Tags: compilar, visual, compilacion

me encuentro compilando un source publico de un programa, el cual al momento de intentar compilar el mismo, no para de arrojarme errores. no soy un experto del tema, pero quería ver si alguien me puede guiar, quizás me este faltando algo para poder compilar el mismo?

edit: agrego el codigo para poder verlo mejor segun la imagen que adjunto, pude resolver varios errores, pero me queda en este punto pidiendo una definicion.

```
    public event KeyboardHookCallback
    {
        add
        {
            KeyboardHookCallback keyDown = this.KeyDown;
            while (true)
            {
                KeyboardHookCallback a = keyDown;
                KeyboardHookCallback callback3 = (KeyboardHookCallback) Delegate.Combine(a, value);
                keyDown = Interlocked.CompareExchange<KeyboardHookCallback>(ref this.KeyDown, callback3, a);
                if (ReferenceEquals(keyDown, a))
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            KeyboardHookCallback keyDown = this.KeyDown;
            while (true)
            {
                KeyboardHookCallback source = keyDown;
                KeyboardHookCallback callback3 = (KeyboardHookCallback) Delegate.Remove(source, value);
                keyDown = Interlocked.CompareExchange<KeyboardHookCallback>(ref this.KeyDown, callback3, source);
                if (ReferenceEquals(keyDown, source))
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio. Por favor en lugar de la imagen pega el código y los errores como texto para que se puedan apreciar mejor.